# Change connection to external data source

Tags: excel, connection-string, excel-2013, excel-external-data

I have an Excel 2013 file which shows data from an external DB2 database. The DB2 database has moved and I would like to change connection information to point to the new IP of the database.

How do I do this in Excel?

At the moment the only way I can find to do this is by creating a new connection and adding all of the views against that it is calling instead of just editing an IP address.

Answer (score 2):

should be simple enough, you just need to update the connection string

Go to...

Data --> Connections

There you should see a list of the connections used in the spreadsheet.
Select the connection(s), then click --> Properties.

On the Connection Properties dialog, you should see two tabs, select --> Definition.

You should find the information in the text area for --> Connection String

Change it and save it...

========================================================

To find connections made through ODBC connections...

Control Panel --> Administrative Tools --> ODBC

Look thru the tabs for *User DSN* -- *System DSN* -- *File DSN*...

Find the **Data Source** name found in the Connection String.

Select and click --> Configure.

Comment: Thanks.  I have looked at the connection string and I couldn't see the address so its got me confused.   I'm testing it locally and the string it produced was `Provider=IBMDADB2.DB2COPY1;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=pdb;Data Source=PDB;Mode=ReadWrite`  Where would I add localhost and I'm not sure that the Provider information is correct?

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I think I found what I needed.  It looks like I needed to use extended properties.  In case its of any use to anyone here it is `Provider=IBMDADB2;Persist Security Info=True;Mode=ReadWrite;Extended Properties="Database=database_name;Hostname=IP Address;Protocol=TCPIP;Port=Port_number;Uid=Database;"`